# Printing array of strings character by character

Tags: c, arrays

I am not very familiar with C yet and faced yet another problem. Usually I found answers to my problems from here but this time I didn't. Probably there is a one but anyways...

Here is the deal. I have an array of strings and I want to print them, each item one their own line. Array ends with NULL.

Here is a simplified version of the code I have atm.

```
print_my_array(char *array[])
{ 

    while(*array != NULL){
        char *item = *array;
        while (item)
        {
            int i = 0;
            printf("%c", item[i]);
            i++;
        }
        printf("\n");
        array++;
    }

}
```

So this is what I believe my code does. I have the array called array. I take the pointer called item and point the first item in array with it. Then I loop over the item and print all the chars one by one. When I have gone through the item I print \n and move to the next item by moving the array pointer and beginning the loop all over.

Answer (score 3):

The inner loop is wrong:

```
while (item)
{
  // all your code
}
```

should be

```
while (*item)
{
  printf("%c", *item++);
}
```

But of course, it'd make way more sense to use `printf("%s\n", *array++);` and skip the inner loop altogether.

Comment: `printf("%s\n", *array++);` Isn't this UB?

Comment: No, why would it be?

Comment: Oh cool thank you @unwind ' printf("%s\n", *array++); ' worked

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I need coffee

Comment: I think @Mr.E is worried about the fact that the `array` parameter appears to be of type `array of pointer to char`, and normally you cannot modify variables of array type.  For instance `char *a[30]; a++;` would be illegal.  But there is special handling for parameters of array type - they are treated identically to pointers.  So the behavior is just as if you had `void print_my_array (char **array) { ... }`.

Comment: @NateEldredge  But that would be a compile-time error, not undefined behavior, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I did an example function, where you loop inside the array with a position until it gets a null value. Later, you see if you printed some character or not, and it tells you if the array was void:

```
 exampleFunction(char array[]){
        int position = 0;

        while(array[position]) {
            printf("%c\n", array[position]);
            position++;
        }

        if(position == 0){
            printf("The array was void.");
        }
}
```

I didn't use pointers, but I think it works anyway. I hope this helps!